# How to stop heroku db processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I was running a migration that had a long update.
I wasn't measuring it so it became quite onerous and start to timeout my users. I got it halted.

BUT, the database was still running the migration and I was caught in a **pg_advisory_lock** issue: basically, I couldn't finish the migration or do anything with the table that I was updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At these awful times you should (and you can safely) use the heroku toolbelt to:

`heroku ps:killall`

With that you kill all the processes running on your db without harming your data.

Hope this helps if you were in hard times like me.

Comment: ›   Warning: ps:killall is not a heroku command.